# Unix dictionary add-on for Mac OS "Dictionary" app?

Tags: linux, reference

I've seen there's other dictionaries you can add to OS X's Dictionary app, but all I can find is spoken languages.  It'd be nice to, while reading a software book, be able to right click a unix function/keyword/etc and have it come up in Dictionary.  Anyone know how to go about this?  For Unix or any language/OS/kernel/etc.?  I know they have Wikipedia built in, which would work, just wondering if there's anything more programming-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your Version of MacOS X, you can create your own content for the Dictionary app. There's a lot of pre-generated material out there, and even a few additional tools to convert stuff from other sources.

- [Dict.org converter](http://dictosx.sourceforge.net/) for pre-Leopard
- [mac-dictionary-kit](http://code.google.com/p/mac-dictionary-kit/) for Leopard onwards. See [blog entry](http://davidtse916.wordpress.com/2008/01/24/adding-dictionaries-to-the-built-in-dictionary-application-in-leopard/) for details - there's more blogs around, google will find you quite a few quotes.
- [Ruby on Rails](http://priithaamer.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-dictionary-for-macosx) Documentation as Dictionary content

Basically you need your "dictionary" input to be well-formatted, and decide which field goes where.

Comment: ahh i figured there wouldn't be anything pre-made.  thanks!